# Use the value column in the dictionary to extract each new column of the appropriate length

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How to do the following in Spark? Please help as I am stuck. Use the value column in the dictionary below to extract each new column of the appropriate length. The dictionary's key should be used as the column name and the first element in the dictionary's value is the starting position of that column's data. While the second element in the dictionary's value is the length of that column's data.

dict = {
"name_1": (1, 15),
"name_2": (16, 40),
"name_3": (56, 40),
"name_4": (96, 30),
"name_5": (44, 12)
}

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly.
You have DataFrame with columns name_1, name_2 etc. and you want to extract from each row of those columns values with length defined in dict?
If yes, let's say that you have following DataFrame:

```
d = [
    ("feg srhtd jhftdht fdhtdh","fserge5ye56u6rut7u ", "fs4gf4t5yy5uyf6y56yr"," fs4t4y5uy6ruyr", "fg45tye5y6ru7ruit7"),
    ("feg kukhgfkugkuklul jhftdht fdhtdh","htj ", "fs4gf4t5yy5uyf6y56yr"," fs4t4y5uy6ruyr", "kukjgkjgk"),
    (" jhftdht fdhtdh","tjygjfgykjfyrj6yjyjyjty ", "gdht"," fs4t4y5uy6ruyr", "jj"),
    ("feg srhtd  ","kjjfgyjg ", "sgrght5dh"," jhyjhgyj", "fg455y6ru7ruit7"),
    ("feg srhtd jhftdht ","fserge5ye56u6rujtjtgjt7u ", "fs4gf4t5yyhftjhfy5uyf6y56yr"," fsjy4t4y5uy6ruyr", "fg45tye5y6ryju7ruit7"),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(d,['name_1','name_2','name_3','name_4', "name_5"])

df.show()

# output
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|              name_1|              name_2|              name_3|           name_4|              name_5|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|feg srhtd jhftdht...| fserge5ye56u6rut7u |fs4gf4t5yy5uyf6y56yr|   fs4t4y5uy6ruyr|  fg45tye5y6ru7ruit7|
|feg kukhgfkugkukl...|                htj |fs4gf4t5yy5uyf6y56yr|   fs4t4y5uy6ruyr|           kukjgkjgk|
|      jhftdht fdhtdh|tjygjfgykjfyrj6yj...|                gdht|   fs4t4y5uy6ruyr|                  jj|
|         feg srhtd  |           kjjfgyjg |           sgrght5dh|         jhyjhgyj|     fg455y6ru7ruit7|
|  feg srhtd jhftdht |fserge5ye56u6rujt...|fs4gf4t5yyhftjhfy...| fsjy4t4y5uy6ruyr|fg45tye5y6ryju7ruit7|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

And dict you defined:

```
data_dict = { "name_1": (1, 15), "name_2": (16, 40), "name_3": (56, 40), "name_4": (96, 30), "name_5": (44, 12) }

# output
{'name_1': (1, 15),
 'name_2': (16, 40),
 'name_3': (56, 40),
 'name_4': (96, 30),
 'name_5': (44, 12)
}
```

So you could iterate through the dict and apply it to pyspark DF:

```
for col_name, (start, length) in data_dict.items():
    # overwrite pyspark DF
    df = df.withColumn(col_name, F.substring(df[col_name], start, length))

df.show()

# output
+---------------+----------+------+------+------+
|         name_1|    name_2|name_3|name_4|name_5|
+---------------+----------+------+------+------+
|feg srhtd jhftd|      t7u |      |      |      |
|feg kukhgfkugku|          |      |      |      |
| jhftdht fdhtdh| yjyjyjty |      |      |      |
|    feg srhtd  |          |      |      |      |
|feg srhtd jhftd|jtjtgjt7u |      |      |      |
+---------------+----------+------+------+------+
```

Empty cells just mean that string was too short to extract something for example length was 20 but you wanted to start at index 44.

@EDIT
Here is faster solution using SQL.

```
def build_sql_query(mapper_dict: dict) -> str:
    partial_query = " ,".join([f"SUBSTRING({col}, {start}, {length} ) AS {col}" for col, (start, length) in mapper_dict.items()])
    return f"SELECT {partial_query} FROM df"

# register view to run SQL query
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
# run query and build new DF
df = spark.sql(build_sql_query(data_dict))

# drop registered view
spark.catalog.dropTempView("df")

df.show()
```

SQL query returned by **build_sql_query** function will look like this:

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(name_1, 1, 15 ) AS name_1,
SUBSTRING(name_2, 16, 40 ) AS name_2,
SUBSTRING(name_3, 56, 40 ) AS name_3,
SUBSTRING(name_4, 96, 30 ) AS name_4,
SUBSTRING(name_5, 44, 12 ) AS name_5 
FROM df
```

So first in order to run this query on **df** you need to register DataFrame as SQL View to make it visible for SQL engine.